# How to calculate cube root in JavaScript without using Math.cbrt() function ? How to Calculate with recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

How can I calculate cube root of any number in JavaScript, Specially i want to calculate with recursion , please answer code .

Comment: use `Math.pow(x, 1 / 3)`

Comment: Thanks , but actually I don't want to use Math.pow or cbrt etc , I want to implement it with recursion or with a for loop .

Answer (score 1):

You could take a numerical approximation with a *heron* function, which uses Newton's method.

```js
function cubeRoot(v) {
    const heron3 = (v, x) => (2 * x + v / (x * x)) / 3;

    var x = v / 4;
        x1 = x;
    
    do {
        x1 = heron3(v, x = x1);
    } while (Math.abs(x - x1) > Number.EPSILON)
    return [x1, x1 * x1 * x1];
}

console.log(...cubeRoot(42));
```